# compiling .c: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, bash, gsl

I have some pre-existing C code (coded by someone else) that should work fine and I am just trying to compile it and run it on my computer. When I try to create an executable with a makefile I get the following message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gsl_ran_binomial", referenced from:
      _develop in develop.o
      _developAllRNAs in develop.o
      _developWithFeedback in develop.o
  "_gsl_ran_exponential", referenced from:
      _randomOrg in G.o
      _mutateBigK in G.o
      _rpois in develop.o
  [And some other gsl_related issues]
  "_gsl_rng_uniform_int", referenced from:
      _randomOrg in G.o
      _mutateTrait in G.o
      _mutateDBM in G.o
      _substitutions in G.o
      _makeGamete in G.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I tried to reinstall `gsl` (`sudo port install gsl`) but the error message remains. I see many hits when googling my error message but so far nothing helped.

**Makefile**

Here is my makefile:

```
LIBS = libs
INCLUDE_PATH=libs/

cli_exec: libraries
    gcc cli/makepopulation.c $(wildcard libraries/*) -I$(INCLUDE_PATH) -o cli_exec

libraries:
    mkdir libraries/
    for dir in $(LIBS); do \
        cd $$dir; \
        gcc -c *.c -I../; \
        mv *.o ../libraries; \
        cd -; \
    done


clean:
    rm -rf libraries/ make_exec
```

I kinda copy-pasted this makefile that I found online and don't get much of it. I edited my question to add my makefile. Basically, my function `int main{}` in the file called metapopulation.c which is in the `cli` directory. the `libs` directory contains all other .c and .h files. and they are compiled and called .o in the directory called `libraries` by the `libraries` function.

Comment: Did you link in the library? Show the command line you're using to link.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Thanks for your comment. See my updated question. Hope this is what you were asking for. In Bash, the command line `make cli_exec`. The `libraries` function seems to work fine, I only receive an error for `cli-exec`. Should I link to my `gsl` directory somehow? I actually linked to the `gsl` directory in each .c file by writing `#include<this/is/a/path/gsl/gsl_randist.h>`

Comment: Confirm you are passing `-lgsl` to the linker and that `-L/path/to/libgsl` is in the library search path (should be, but check)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't quite understand what a "linker" is, neither what is the "library search path". No, I am not passing (at least not actively/consciously) `-lgsl`.

Comment: You have your Makefile, but I don't see a specific reference to `lgsl` anywhere in it. When you build with libgsl, your minimum compile string is `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o progname progname.c -lgsl`. The `-lgsl` tells the linker `ld` (called after gcc automatically) to link the executable to `libgsl`. I don't see where you do that. In your Makefile, just add `-lgsl` after `-o cli_exec` and that should work.

Comment: Ok, I didn't get everything but that worked! I just had to add `-lgsl` after -o cli_exec as you said! Thanks a lot. Can you make an answer out of your comment? Thanks a lot! Btw, as aside question do you know a good online tutorial in order to acquire a bit of knowledge about compiling, makefile and things (I don't realize how broad is my aside question).

Comment: There are a lot. Just a few searches will be enough. The key is to always enable warnings. So you compile string will be generically `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o execname execname.c (plus any needed libs or paths)` Makefiles, while great, can be confusing when you are learning the basics. Forget about them for now. Unless you have 10+ sources and object to string together, just use the command line. It will make you a better programmer. I'll write a short answer tomorrow. Have a good night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a specific reference to `lgsl` anywhere in your `Makefile`. When you build with `libgsl`, your minimum compile string is:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o progname progname.c -lgsl
```

The `-lgsl` tells the linker `ld` (that is called after gcc automatically) to link the executable to `libgsl`. I don't see where you do that. In your `Makefile`, just add `-lgsl` after `-o cli_exec` and that should work. E.g.:

```
gcc cli/makepopulation.c $(wildcard libraries/*) -I$(INCLUDE_PATH) -o cli_exec -lgsl
```

Answer (score -1):

Possibly your PC doesn't have GNU Scientific Library (GSL).
You can install it first ,
[install-gnu-scientific-library-gsl-on-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490465/install-gnu-scientific-library-gsl-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-terminal),
and then run compilation.